# Accessing disjoint entries in global HashMap for lifetime of thread in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-local, lazy-static

my current project requires recording some information for various events that happen during the execution of a thread. These events are saved in a global struct index by the thread id:

```rust
RECORDER1: HashMap<ThreadId, Vec<Entry>> = HashMap::new();
```

Every thread appends new `Entry` to its vector. Therefore, threads access "disjoint" vectors. Rust requires synchronization primitives to make the above work of course. So the real implementation looks like:

```rust
struct Entry {
    // ... not important.
}

#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct ThreadId;

// lazy_static necessary to initialize this data structure.
lazy_static! {
    /// Global data structure. Threads access disjoint entries based on their unique thread id.
    /// "Outer" mutex necessary as lazy_static requires sync (so cannot use RefCell).
    static ref RECORDER2: Mutex<HashMap<ThreadId, Vec<Entry>>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}
```

This works, but all threads contend on the same global lock. It would be nice if a thread could "borrow" its respective vector for the lifetime of the thread so it could write all the entries it needs without needing to lock every time (I understand the outer lock is necessary for ensuring threads don't insert into the HashMap at the same time).

We can do this by adding an Arc and some more interior mutability via a Mutex for the values in the HashMap:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref RECORDER: Mutex<HashMap<ThreadId, Arc<Mutex<Vec<Entry>>>>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}
```

Now we can "check out" our entry when a thread is spawned:

```rust
fn local_borrow() {
    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut recorder = RECORDER.lock().expect("Unable to acquire outer mutex lock.");
        let my_thread_id: ThreadId = ThreadId {}; // Get thread id...

        // Insert entry in hashmap for our thread.
        // Omit logic to check if key-value pair already existed (it shouldn't).
        recorder.insert(my_thread_id.clone(), Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())));

        // Get "reference" to vector
        let local_entries: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Entry>>> = recorder
            .get(&my_thread_id)
            .unwrap() // We just inserted this entry, so unwrap.
            .clone();  // Clone on the Arc to acquire a "copy".

        // Lock once, use multiple times.
        let mut local_entries: MutexGuard<_> = local_entries.lock().unwrap();
        local_entries.push(Entry {});
        local_entries.push(Entry {});

    });
}
```

This works and is what I want. However, due to API constraints I have to access the MutexGuard from widely different places across the code without the ability to pass the MutexGuard as an argument to functions. So instead I use a thread local variable:

```rust
thread_local! {
    /// This variable is initialized lazily. Due to API constraints, we use this thread_local! to
    /// "pass" LOCAL_ENTRIES around.
    static LOCAL_ENTRIES: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Entry>>> = {
        let mut recorder = RECORDER.lock().expect("Unable to acquire outer mutex lock.");
        let my_thread_id: ThreadId = ThreadId {}; // Get thread id...

         // Omit logic to check if key-value pair already existed (it shouldn't).
        recorder.insert(my_thread_id.clone(), Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())));
        // Get "reference" to vector

        recorder
        .get(&my_thread_id)
        .unwrap() // We just inserted this entry, so unwrap.
        .clone()  // Clone on the Arc to acquire a "copy".
    }
}
```

I cannot make `LOCAL_ENTRIES: MutexGuard<_>` since `thread_local!` requires a `'static` lifetime. So currently I have to `.lock()` every time I want to access the thread-local variable:

```rust
fn main() {
    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        // Record important message.
        LOCAL_ENTRIES.with(|entries| {
            // We have to lock every time we want to write to LOCAL_ENTRIES. It would be nice
            // to lock once and hold on to the MutexGuard for the lifetime of the thread, but
            // this is not possible to due the lifetime on the MutextGuard.
            let mut entries = entries.lock().expect("Unable to acquire lock");
            entries.push(Entry {});
        });
    });
}
```

Sorry for all the code and explanation but I'm really stuck and wanted to show why it doesn't work and what I'm trying to get working. How can one get around this in Rust?

Or am I getting hung up on cost of the mutex locking? For any `Arc<Mutex<Vec<Entry>>>`, the lock will always be unlocked so the cost of doing the atomic locking will be tiny?

Thanks for any thoughts. Here is the complete example in [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=adecd18a688efbaece0ddb3beb9018ab).

Comment: So is it correct to say that no other thread needs to access the vec until the owning thread is finished? (if you did manage to keep the guard around for the life of the thread then no-one else would be able to access it anyway)

Comment: @harmic yes, that is correct and yes, the guard would guarantee exclusive access anyways. I feel like this would be straightforward in C++ but in Rust the lifetimes just don't work out.